# Is apache kafka Mirror maker officially released, I would like to use the stable version in our prod environment for disaster recovery

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I would like to use Mirror Maker 2 for our data pipeline and take advantage of its features in prod but I don't find anything related to whether its officially release or still beta version.

Answer (score 1):

MirrorMaker 2 was released as part of Apache Kafka 2.4.0. You can verify this in the [release notes](https://archive.apache.org/dist/kafka/2.4.0/RELEASE_NOTES.html), and see the specific JIRA [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7500).

Comment: I am trying to use this version for my DR strategy, do you have any sample config which I can refer to.

Comment: I've answered your original question, please start a new post if you have a new question.

Comment: @MuthuKumar Did you read any of the linked resources between the JIRA or Kafka github? https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/connect/mirror

Comment: Yep, I had gone through KIP JIRA and link detailing mirror maker, above github I hadn't viewed yet. Thanks for sharing!